# WinForms tab order issue

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a DevExpress Wizard Control. Here is it's tab order:

[image]

I want to change focused control by TAB button press, but when i do it focus not changed.
What cn be wrong here?

Comment: then what happens? the cursor goes outside the layoutconrtrol?

Comment: @Nimesh Coursor stands on field what i'd clicked by myself.